# macros on ajax-heavy page

Tags: google-chrome, macros

I'm looking for a macro system for a page which is heavily ajax-based.
The extensions I have found only works on static pages (look for a field called "xxx", type "yyy", submit)

What I need is

- search for "(more)"
- click on it
- text gets downloaded into a div (random id) with a "..." div.
- Click on that div, a menu appears
- Click on the menuitem "Report" (random id)
- A popup gets loaded by ajax
- Click on the word "Spam"
- A button "Submit" appears
- Click on that button. Popup disappears
- (repeat)

I've tried

- Dejaclick
- Chromium browser automation
- iMacros

None seems to work on dynamic ajax pages.

Answer (score 0):

> ... for a page which is heavily ajax-based.

I had this issue myself. HTML-based tools like [iMacros](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/imacros-for-chrome/cplklnmnlbnpmjogncfgfijoopmnlemp/reviews?hl=en) or [Selenium IDE](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/kantu-browser-automation/gcbalfbdmfieckjlnblleoemohcganoc) will not work reliably with complex web pages because they need a stable page to find their elements, not appearing and disappearing javascript code (like you said).

But I had good results with [Sikuli](http://www.sikuli.org/) and Kantu [Visual Browser Automation](https://a9t9.com/kantu/browser-automation), which is just like Sikuli, but inside a Chromium web browser.  Both tools use *image recognition and simulate real mouse clicks*, so they work great with ajax-heavy web apps!

The difference is that Sikuli runs on the desktop, but Kantu runs just inside its own browser, so it does not take over the desktop and you can continue to do other things while it is running.